# Is it possible to write expression in message.properties file?

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-2.0

I am displaying the text in my app through message.properties now on certain condition i have to display similar message with slight changes. Is it possible to check condition in message properties only like :

```
if (a == salary) {
     code = your salary for this month is {0}
}else if (a == tax) {
     code = your tax for this month is {0}
}
```

Now in this case the only difference in text is salary and tax instead of checking it in controller or i want to check this condition in message.properties only. Is it possible ? If yes how ?

Thanks ! in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to check in the messages.properties, just change your code to

```
your {0} for this month is {1}
```

and pass `a` as argument in the message like

```
g.message(code: 'adminUsers.restore.confirm.message', args: [a, 'XXX'])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but that was not what i am asking. Actually i couldn't explain in example the simple thing i want to ask is can we check condition in message.properties ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Since properties is only properties file. But I know there are plugins that expand capabilities to work with properties files. I think in your case you have to split 'logic' part to your controller\service and leave only message in *.properties file

Comment: Thank you Andrii. I will research if there is any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create conditional messages to deal with plural/singular (using MessageFormat / choice).

But what you are asking for is not the right use of that capability.

And  `your {0} for this month is {1}` is also a bad idea, as it will mess up translation.
It is possible that "tax" and "salary" have different genders in some languages, and that can affect words far away in the sentence.

It is best to have full sentences in properties, no tricks like conditionals, substitutions, etc.

Why would you want this anyway? Saving a few words?

Comment: I have complete word in my application here in application i just want to make it simple. Anyway thank you for your answer.